# Deploy java web app in ubuntu tomcat server, Showing server not reachable error in client side

Tags: java, ubuntu, tomcat, web-applications

In my ubuntu server , I have installed tomcat9 using `sudo apt-get install tomcat9`. and then I start a server using `sudo service start tomcat9` . Now it is running (also installed jdk ). But to check my web app in browser `http:myServer'sIPaddress:8080` or `http:myServer'sIPaddress:8080/index.html` is showing server not reachable error. Do I need any extra configuration for serving static content. in my server index.html is present in the directory  `/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/ROOT`. I also allowd 8080 by using `sudo ufw allow 8080` this command

Comment: Try “localhost:8080”

Comment: I have installed tomcat in in my ubuntu server . But I'm trying to reach from my local computer's browser

Comment: Is the server on a local private network or in a cloud service or a dedicated or what?

Comment: Its is  aws EC2 instance

Comment: By default a security group for EC2 doesn't allow port 8080 - only port 22.  Have you opened the port in the security group?

Comment: Now I changed my apache serving port as 80 from 8080 , Now its working fine... :)